# Select 1 specific value from list result

Tags: python, string

I want to select one specific value from a list result string using python.
Ex:

```
mystring= ['abc', 'cde', 'def', 'ghk', 'xyz']
```

I want to select and print out each result that comes between `"abc"` and `"xyz"` like:

```
result1 = cde
result2 = def
result3 = ghk
```

Comment: You want 1 specific value or each result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
import re

x = 'abc, cde, def, ghk, xyz'
m = re.search('abc, (.+?), xyz', x)
if m:
    result1, result2, result3 = m.group(1).split(', ')
    print(result1, result2, result3, sep="\n")
```

Output:
`cde`
`ef`
`ghk`

Comment: Just write `result1, result2, result3 = m.group(1).split(', ')` you want to use that regex. And there's no reason to assign this variables as empty strings. Aslo you can `print(result1, result2, result3, sep="\n")`. But your idea to assign each value to different string variable is not the best at all, as well as using regex for this.

Comment: sure, like that.

Comment: work like a charm, thank you. 1 more things, how can i use other variable instead of a fixed "abc"?

Comment: Try this.
`c = 'abc'`,
`d = 'xyz'`,
`x = 'abc, cde, def, ghk, xyz'`,
`m = re.search(c+', (.+?), '+d, x)`

Comment: @Derpington, you can take a look on my answer. It doesn't use regular expressions and gives an example of usage with not fixed boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to form list of items between your delimiters.

```
string = "abc, cde, def, ghk, xyz"
start, end = "abc", "xyz"
res = [s for s in string[string.index(start) + len(start) + 2: string.index(end) - 2].split(", ")]  # len(", ") = 2
print(*(f"result{i + 1} = {s}" for i, s in enumerate(res)), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
result1 = cde
result2 = def
result3 = ghk
```